# PHP + Android - How to know which user is trying to login and if he is logged in

Tags: android

I have an Android app that has an initial login screen, sending the credentials to a PHP server. Afterwards, I want to access other parts of the server that require the user to be logged in. 
I know that unlike with web browsers, I cannot store session data.

When I access those parts, how can the server make sure that the user is the user, and that he is logged in?

**What I'm thinking:**
Judging from the questions/answers in stack overflow, a proper way is for, when a user logs in successfully, we give him an authentication code, both server and client store that code, and then when I need to do something that requires me to be logged on I send that code and server see if a match occurs.

My doubt is regarding the match process. Assuming it is like stored in a database in the server side, we have like the code associated to a username.
**Isn't it possible (but not probable?) that a duplicate code can be generated for two different users?** Should I then make sure in the database that each code is unique before adding it, or add like the username encrypted to the code, so that each code is different? Or is the probability of generating two equal authentication codes so low that it doesn't even matter?

Also, how should I store the authentication code on the Android side, assuming that when I close the app I want to get the authentication code and not having to re-introduce the credentials? Or is this bad practice?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might would like to use tokens.

When first time user logs in you give them a token - if the credentials are correct. And from that point the user will use that token for each request. In the back-end you can set up a scheduler to clean up these tokes after a while.

**Isn't it possible (but not probable?) that a duplicate code can be generated for two different users?**

It's possible if your implementation is incorrect. This is something you should take care of - OR you can use a package, which will take care of most of this authentication part. Like [OAuth](https://www.oauth.com/)

**Should I then make sure in the database that each code is unique before adding it, or add like the username encrypted to the code, so that each code is different?**

If you are going to use an authentication package, then you dont have to care about it - most likely. Otherwise you can set up the field as unique in the database.

**Or is the probability of generating two equal authentication codes so low that it doesn't even matter?**

Being able to identify your users is always important. For example admins and clients on the websites are used to be stored in the same user table/collection/whatever. And if you generate the same token for both admin and client, then it's possible that during the permission check you get back only one of the record from the database - assuming that it's unique and the admin will end up with client permission or the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll look into authentication packages in more detail.